# How to write function that takes in a string message and returns a list of string messages with pagination

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to write a function that takes in a string message and returns a list of string messages with pagination if needed.

This is what I have

```
import textwrap

def smart_collect():
    text = input('Please Enter a text: ')
    dedented_text = textwrap.dedent(text).strip()
    wrap_text = textwrap.wrap(dedented_text, width=212)
    max_page = len(wrap_text)

    for i in range(0, max_page):
        print(f'{wrap_text[i]} ({i+1}/{max_page})')


smart_collect()
```

#### Input Text/String:

```
As a reminder, you have an appointment with Dr. Smith tomorrow at 
3:30 pm. If you are unable to make this appointment, please call our 
customer service line at least 1 hour before your scheduled 
appointment time.
```

#### My Output:

```
As a reminder, you have an appointment with Dr. Smith tomorrow at(1/1)
3:30 pm. If you are unable to make this appointment, please call our 
3:30: command not found
customer service line at least 1 hour before your scheduled customer: 
command not found
appointment time.
```

#### Expected Results

As an example, the following message has 212 characters:

```
As a reminder, you have an appointment with Dr. Smith tomorrow at 
3:30 pm. If you are unable to make this appointment, please call our 
customer service line at least 1 hour before your scheduled 
appointment time.
```

The message should be sent in two chunks as such:

```
As a reminder, you have an appointment with Dr. Smith tomorrow at 
3:30 pm. If you are unable to make this appointment, please call our 
customer service  (1/2)
```

and

```
line at least 1 hour before your scheduled appointment time. (2/2)
```

Comment: Maybe try replacing `return [wrap_text]` with `return wrap_text.split("\n")`

Comment: This split the string after 100 characters and adds a comma in the same line

Comment: Check my answer below and see if it works for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `textwrap.fill()` here for your purposes:

> Wraps the single paragraph in text, and returns a single string containing the wrapped paragraph.

Instead, you need to use `textwrap.wrap()`

> Wraps the single paragraph in text (a string) so every line is at most width characters long. Returns a list of output lines, without final newlines.

Since it already returns a list, there isn't much left for you to do here.

```py
def smart_collect():
    text = input('Please Enter a text: ')
    dedented_text = textwrap.dedent(text).strip()
    wrap_text = textwrap.wrap(dedented_text, width=100)
    return wrap_text

print(smart_collect())
```

Now that you have a list of strings that are `width=100` characters long, you can now do whatever it is you want with your strings. For example, if you wanted to print them you would do:

```py
for each in smart_collect():
    print(each)
```

Now if you wanted to add pagination, you could do this:

```py
list_strings = smart_collect()
max_page = len(list_strings)
for i in range(0, max_page):
    print(f'{list_strings[i]} ({i+1}/{max_page})')
```

For your input, your result (with width=100) looks like this:

> As a reminder, you have an appointment with Dr. Smith tomorrow at 3:30 pm. If you are unable to make (1/3)
>   this appointment, please call our customer service line at least 1 hour before your scheduled (2/3)
>   appointment time. (3/3)

Comment: I can see it returns a list fine. but how will I be to get new line pagination? I hope you have seen the expected result

Comment: I want to split the long string into chunks string after a certain number of characters

Comment: Print the items in the list one at a time. Or add in the new line character in between. If you want a page count do len(list) and that will be max pages, then count each one as you print it out. Beyond that what I gave you gives you the output you need, now it depends on how you are displaying it to help you further.

Comment: @DanielOtieno I updated my code to add pagination.  I tested it and it works properly.

Comment: What output are you expecting to get? The code I gave does pagination in the exact method you gave and uses a width of 100 characters which you can change to any length. I’m not sure what other output you could want.

Comment: You can’t edit it in that way, when you return it will only send out the first item of the loop which would only be the first message and not the others. To loop through multiples you can print them inside the function and return nothing, or you can print them outside of the function and return the list. But you can’t do only half of one.

Comment: Thank you for the support, but I am still not getting the correct output 

here is my updated code 

```def smart_collect():
    text = input('Please Enter a text: ')
    dedented_text = textwrap.dedent(text).strip()
    wrap_text = textwrap.wrap(dedented_text, width=100)
    max_page = len(wrap_text)
    for i in range(0, max_page):
        return(f'{wrap_text[i]} ({i+1}/{max_page})')```

Comment: You cannot return in the middle of a for loop or it will only return the first item of the loop. You have to print inside the function or outside the function. Can’t return only one item of a list. Return stops the function from continuing.

Comment: Apart from the `return` is the update code correct? sorry I am a beginner and I am trying to understand every concept

Comment: Yes everything else looks fine to me.

Comment: If there is any part you don’t understand let me know and I will explain what it is. I would recommend using my exact code and testing it, then making small changes and testing one change at a time to make sure the change is correct.

Comment: I have updated the code above, Kindly can you review it

Comment: I don't where I am doing it wrong but it breaks whenever I paste text on the terminal to run it hence getting weird output. let me update the input and output I am getting

Comment: The text you have above has new lines at the end of every line meaning if you directly copy and paste that to terminal it will send each line one at a time. So your first line is getting sent and processed and then each new line is just like you pasted that line in terminal meaning it thinks it should be code, causing an error. Do a delete at the end of every line in your input to make sure it’s actually a single paragraph and not a bunch of separate lines before using it as an input.

Comment: Thank you very Much Sir. It's now working fine. once again Thank you